# System.NullReferenceException on ICollection.Add

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, error-handling

I have the following piece of code in my project (Xamarin cross-platform), the line that is giving me the error is:

```
med.Medicine_Incident.Add(med_inc);
```

I am not sure how the line is null-referenced, because as we can see, I have set the values to the `med_inc` properties (time and dosage), also I have set the values for the med properties (name and description). (`Medicine` and `Medicine_Incident` classes at the bottom)

```
this.BindingContext = new Medicine();

var med = (Medicine)BindingContext;

this.BindingContext = new Medicine_Incident();
var med_inc = (Medicine_Incident)BindingContext;

Medicine_Name = "Insulin";
Medicine_Desc = "Because normal digestion interferes with insulin taken by mouth, insulin must be injected";
med.Medicine_Name = Medicine_Name;
med.Medicine_Desc = Medicine_Desc;

med_inc.Dosage = Insulin_Dosage;

if (Insulin_Morning_Toggled)
{
    //Morning 8 a.m , year 2015 December 31
    Time = new DateTime(2050, 12, 31, 08, 00, 0);
    med_inc.Time = Time;

    med.Medicine_Incident.Add(med_inc);
}
```

`Medicine` class:

```
public class Medicine : User_Profiles
{
    [Ignore]
    public virtual ICollection<Medicine_Incident> Medicine_Incident { get; set; }

    // This is my link to the User_Profiles PrimaryKey; A foreigh Key
    //public int User_ProfilesId { get; set; }

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Medicine_Name { get; set; }
    public string Medicine_Desc { get; set; }

    public Medicine()
    {
        Medicine_Name = "";
        Medicine_Desc = "";
    }

    public Medicine(string medicine_Name, string medicine_Desc)
    {
        Medicine_Name = medicine_Name;
        Medicine_Desc = medicine_Desc;
    }
}
```

`Medicine_Incident` class:

```
public class Medicine_Incident : Medicine
{
    //[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    //public int Id { get; set; }

    // This is my link to the medicine PrimaryKey; A foreigh Key
    //public int MedicineId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public int Dosage { get; set; }

    public Medicine_Incident()
    {
        // (1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM)
        Time = default(DateTime);
        Dosage = 0;
    }

    public Medicine_Incident(DateTime medicine_Time, int dosage)
    {
        Time = medicine_Time;
        Dosage = dosage;
    }
}
```

Could the error arise from the `[ignore]` tag in this line of the `Medicine` class:

```
[Ignore]
public virtual ICollection<Medicine_Incident> Medicine_Incident { get; set; }
```

If it is so, then there is another problem, as I am unable to use that line without `[ignore]`. If I do, I get a different error:

> System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[LoginSystem.Models.Medicine]

Comment: Where do you initialize the `Medicine_Incident` property on the `Medicine` class?  Seems like that's what's `null` here.

Comment: I am sorry i didnt quite get it, how should that initialization look like?

Comment: in the constructor of Medicine, you need to initialize the Medicine_Incident property, otherwise it will be null when you try to add to it.

Comment: Normally I would initialize a property in the object's constructor.  What should that property be?  (Since `ICollection<T>` is an interface, you need a concrete type.)  For example: `this.Medicine_Incident = new List<Medicine_Incident>();`

Comment: Just to let you know, it is better if you write your first lines like this ``var med = new Medicine(); this.BindingContext = med;  var med_inc =new Medicine_Incident(); this.BindingContext = med_inc;`` And you do realize you are overwriting your this.BindingContext?

Comment: Just realized... it is kind of funny to see that you didnt initialize the ICollection but you are initializing the DateTime property with ``default(DateTime)`` which is a useless line of code since DateTime is a struct and that doesnt have to be initialized.